# trying to make two items in a grid appear at the same height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a resume with a skills section featuring professional skills and personal skills, I want both sections to appear in columns that are at the same height with one floating left and the other floating right.. attached is an image of what I want and what I have...[top image mine, bottom is template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmXfq.jpg)

Can anyone tell me why "Personal" is floating slightly lower than "Professional"?

Here is my code and CSS.
CODE

```
<section class="skills">
            <h2 class="resumesectionheader"> Capabilities/Skills</h2>
            <ul class="listofskills">
                
                <li> <h3> Professional</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li> 
                </ul>    
                </li>
                <li> <h3> Personal</h3>
                 <ul>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li>
                    <li> Blah</li> 
                </ul>  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
.skills > ul {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 2rem}
```

Comment: I see no problem with your current CSS, it works well. Would you mind creating a reproducible snippet here in the SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sameer pointed out, there's nothing wrong with the code you shared. However, I do notice two additional CSS classes namely `resumesectionheader` and `listofskills`.

Since the code works fine without those eliminate them one at a time to find which one clashes with the `skills` class.

[image]

[image: smallest screen resolution]